# jquery html textarea plugin for ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, jquery-plugins

Has anyone found html textarea plugin that works with iPad?

If i use any plug-in to convert textarea to html rich editor, it hides textarea and adds iframe in place of it. When i click on iframe in windows i can add/edit text like a textarea. Where as in iPad i click on it it doesn't pop up keyboard as its not a textbox or textarea instead its iframe.

i need it for jquery based chat which can run on both computer and iPad. So i need to allow simple formating of text like bold, italic, font etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mobile Safari in iOS prior to version 5 doesn't support `contenteditable` or `designMode`, which is the built-in browser editing functionality that underpins most JavaScript rich text editors. You'll need to find another way, such as drawing your own caret and collecting input in a (possibly off-screen) textarea, which is what [Google Docs](http://docs.google.com/), [ACE](http://ace.ajax.org/) and [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) do. This is quite involved though.

Another alternative is the Stack Overflow approach, which uses Markdown in a textarea with formatting buttons.

Comment: so isnt there any plugin for this purpose?

Comment: @Johal: I'm not aware of a jQuery plug-in that provides a non-contenteditable editor. As I mentioned in my answer, it's not a simple thing to develop. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled on **[MarkItUp](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/)**, which seems to provide a good fall-back HTML (and BBCode) editing mode for mobile browsers that don't support `contenteditable` properly yet.

Looks like a good alternative solution if you want to give you mobile users a slightly better experience than just editing raw HTML.